# the gui didn't appear

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

i don't know why the gui didn't appear

```
  /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package anagramword;

/**
 *
 * @author teteh
 */
public class gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form gui
     */
    public String textword;
    public char[] temp;
    static int size;
    public gui() {
        initComponents();
        //setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        word = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnSubmit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        hasil = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("Masukkan Kata");

        btnSubmit.setText("Acak");
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSubmitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Anagram Word");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addGap(99, 99, 99))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnSubmit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 81, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(word, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(hasil, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 170, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 58, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(word, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(btnSubmit, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(hasil, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Anagramword ana = new Anagramword();

        textword=word.getText();
        size = textword.length();
        temp = textword.toCharArray();

        if (size <= 2) {
            System.out.println("Maaf Minimal 3 Huruf");
        } else {
            ana.acak(textword, size);
            ana.runAnagram(size);
            ana.display();
        }
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new gui().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        //new gui().setVisible(true);
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSubmit;
    private javax.swing.JLabel hasil;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField word;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

when i run the app the gui didn't appear but it said build successfull. i have the setVisible(true) but the gui never appear.help please i must miss something in the code or wrong using.

Comment: @user1822857 Runs fine here. How are you running this program? IDE, java version?

Comment: It shows up for me. I had to comment out the code in `btnSubmitActionPerformed` (since I dont have access to the Anagramword class), but that is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you press the start button in netbeans it try to run another class... In your class gui try to right click -> Run As -> Java Application.

Otherwise Right Click on Project -> Run -> Main Class -> Browse.. and select `anagramword.gui`